# Scoping mecanism with nodejs and require

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

Trying to perform unit test of client-side javascript using nodejs and jasmine-node.
I was able to create the window and document variables, a $ variable, setup the environment (with npm, don't forget to define NODE_PATH!). But now I am stuck on this.

The functions I want to test are within a module. I can import (require) the module but the variable in which the module is imported in is not accessible from nodejs (or the jasmine spec file for the same reason I imagine).

Here is the module:

```
var test_module = (function () {
  var init = function () {
    return "toto";
  }

  return { init: init };
})();
```

In the variable test_module, we should find the variable containing the dictionary with all the exported function (here only one called init).

In nodejs:

```
> require('test.js');
{}
> test_module
ReferenceError: test_module is not defined
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

I am not sure to understand how the scoping works in nodejs. I tried to put:

```
global.test_module = (function () {
```

and this works but this is not what I want to do. My javascript is supposed to run in the browser once tested, and global won't do...

*Side note: Unit testing of client-side javascript using a command line, browserless and serveress solution would deserve a god tutorial I guess. There are some out there but they are usually incomplete.*

Comment: You also need to export your module `module.exports = test_module`, at the end of your module file. Then from your main file `var test_module = require("test.js");`

Comment: you shouldn't test browser code in node.js

Comment: To htatche: Yes but that's a nodejs thing... How the browser will manage this. I think it won't like this exports business. The purpose here is to unit tests a client-side javascript module, so a module loaded from a <script> tag in an html page.

Comment: To vkurchatkin: Ok so how do you unit test through the command line (without having to load a browser page) then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to htatche's answer, I found a workaround (it seems that client-side javascript unit testing is the land of workaround...):

```
var test_module = (function () {
  var init = function () {
    return "toto";
  }

  return { init: init };
})();

if(typeof exports != 'undefined'){
    module.exports = test_module;
}
```

Explained here: http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/writing_for_node_and_the_browser/
This way I keep nodejs and the browser happy.

Comment: This is a common.js pattern, look into that more.